# How to automatically sort and remove unused imports in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

When types are removed and their using statements linger how can I quickly reorganize my using statements and remove dead ones?

Answer (score 8):

Use the Hotkey combination:

> Ctrl+R, Ctrl+G